# Do apps like WhatsApp keep an always live connection with server?

Tags: android, ios, networking, tcp, xmpp

I'm creating an application that has to realtime be live with the server. I'm not sure whether to have an always live (or checking with server every 2mins) app because it might drain the battery. What are my alternatives?

Comment: push notifications?

Comment: use services if you update data on server at particular interval of time

Answer (score 7):

WhatsApp uses XMPP (eXtensible Messaging and Presence Protocol) to handle the message delivery system.
XMPP is mostly like HTTP where the client opens the socket with the XMPP server and keeps it open as long as the client is logged in. It's not like the regular REST API where the client opens the socket send/receive the data and close the socket. The socket is opened as long as you are signed in. In case of WhatsApp that's eternity (not really, WhatsApp reconnects automatically if the connection terminates)

Answer (score 2):

As written, use push notifications (working even with closed app) or socket connection (working with app on the background). If the app is on foreground, you can use whatever you want - screen will take most of the battery...

Answer (score 0):

Whats app using XMPP server, as like mentioned in above answer. For free of cost, If you want to create a messenger application like whats app. Tou can use some of the free real-time databases are available in the market like "FireBase" server.

You can get sample code here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

and further information regarding the firebase server and required libraries you can find here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/